# Iterating over dictionary in Python and using each value

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to iterate over a dictionary that looks like this:

```
account_data = {"a": "44196397",
                "b": "2545086098",
                "c": "210623431",
                "d": "1374059147440820231",
                "e": "972970759416111104",
                "f": "1060627757812641792",
                "g": "1368361032796700674",
                "h": "910899153772916736",
                "i": "887748030304329728",
                "j": "1381341090",
                "k": "2735504155",
                "l": "150324112", }
```

The goal is to use each ID to scrape some data, therefor I got a method that takes the corresponding userID and gets the data from it. At first I had a method for every ID in the dict, but now I want to change it so that I got one method which iterates over the dictionary, takes one ID at a time and makes the API request, if finished the next is made and so on.

The problem is I can't iterate over the dictionary, I always just access the first one in here.

I am relatively new to Python since I mainly used Java.
Maybe dictionary is the wrong data structure for this task?

Any help appreciated.

Edit:

This is my old code to iterate over the dictionary:

```
def iterate_over_dict():
    for key, value in account_data.items():
        return value
```

I then continue with using the id in this function:

```
def get_latest_data():

    chosen_id = iterate_over_dict()
    print('id: ', chosen_id)
    # get my tweets
    tweets = get_tweets_from_user_id(chosen_id)
    # get tweet_id of latest tweet
    tweet_id = tweets.id.values[0]
    # get tweet_text of latest tweet
    tweets = tweets.text.values[0]
    # check if new tweet - if true -> check if contains
    data = check_for_new_tweet(tweet_id, tweets)

    if data is not None:
        print("_________")
        print('1 ', data)
```

But I always only use the first one. I think in Java it wouldn't be a problem for me since I can just use an index to iterate from 0 to n, but is there something similar for dictionaries? I also want to run the get_latest_data method every time a new ID is chosen from the dict

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't iterate over the dictionary"?  What did you try?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops

Comment: where is your code showing how your trying to iterate over the dictionary

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I just edited my question, hope it is enough background for understanding the question now

Comment: your issue is as soon as you start iterating over the items in the first loop you then return which means stop the function and you hand back only the first value

Comment: @ChrisDoyle yeah correct. What I need is a function that returns one ID, then calls the API and the function returns the next ID, but I have no clue how to do that. Do you have any hints?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use for loop for iteration.

```py
dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
for key, value in dict.items():
  print(key+" "+ str(value))

for key in dict:
  print(key+ " "+str(dict[key]))
```

The first one iterates over items and gives you keys and values. The second one iterates over keys and then it is accessing value from the dictionary using the key.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by turning the dictionary into a list comprised of only the values.

```
val = list(account_data.values())
```

Would give you `["44196397", "2545086098", "210623431"...]`

Which you can then very easily iterate over in a for loop without needing to worry about the key at all.

Comment: this looks good, I can simply iterate over a list no?

Comment: Exactly yes, and this gives you a list